# Finding Permutations

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

Let $a=6$, $b=12$, $c=7$ and $d=2$. Find a permutation $\mu$ such that

$$(a\ b\ c\ d) =\mu(1\ 2\ 3\ 4)\mu^{-1}.$$

Show that the permutation, $\mu$, really does satisfy the equation.

So far I have tried putting the $\mu$ and $\mu^{-1}$ together, does that cancel out?
And where do I go from here?

Comment: If $v=(a_1,a_2,a_3,...)(b_1,b_2,b_3,...)$ then $\mu v \mu^{-1}=(\mu (a_1),\mu (a_2),\mu(a_3),...)(\mu (b_1),\mu (b_2),\mu(b_3),...)$

Answer (score 1):

I assume you compose right-to-left. Then note the following. $(a b c d)$ takes $a$ to $b$, and $(1 2 3 4)$ take $1$ to $2$. Let $\mu$ take $1$ to $a$ and $2$ to $b$, so that $\mu^{-1}$ takes $a$ to $1$ and $b$ to $2$. Now check where $\mu (1 2 3 4) \mu^{-1}$ takes $a$.

And, no, permutations do not usually permute, so you cannot cancel $\mu$ and $\mu^{-1}$.

Comment: Thank you for your help! So do I need to substitute the values of abcd in before hand or does that come in later? And I am a bit confused as to what you mean by let μ take 1 to a, what would the permutation look like in that case?

Answer (score 1):

Let $v=(ab)$ then $\mu v\mu^{-1}(\mu (a))=\mu(b)$ and $\mu v\mu^{-1}(\mu (b))=\mu(a)$.

For $c$ is not $\mu(a)$,$\mu (b)$ we have $\mu^{-1}(c)$ is not $a,b$. It follows that $v(\mu^{-1}(c))=\mu^{-1}(c)$,hence $\mu v\mu^{-1}(c)=c$ therefore $$ \mu v\mu^{-1}=(\mu (a) \mu(b))$$

You can use this for your case

Then $$(a b c d)=(\mu(1) \mu(2) \mu(3) \mu (4))$$
So
$$\mu(1)=a=6$$

$$\mu(2)=b=12$$

$$\mu(3)=c=7$$

$$\mu(4)=d=2$$

(I commented general formula that I used)

Comment: Thank you for your help! So what do I do after this step? Or is this the final step?

Comment: It is Final step I wrote all the steps and formulas that i used. Can you understand it?

Comment: I am trying to understand why we leave it just as (1)=a=6 etc... can you please help me understand?

Comment: This two permutation are same so it should be equal isn't it?